# Bootstrap AKS agent nodes through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I am currently using terraform to create k8s cluster which is working perfectly fine. Once the nodes are provisioned, I want to run a few bash commands on any one of the node. So far, `null_resource` seems like an option since it is a cluster and we are unaware of the node names/IPs.  However, I am unable to determine what should be the value of `connection` block since [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/kubernetes_cluster.html#http_application_routing) does not export the IP address of the load balancer or the vm names. The question mark needs the correct value in the below:

```
resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
  triggers = { "${join(",", azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.id)}" }
  connection = { type = ssh 
                 user = <user>
                 password = <password>
                 host = <?>
                 host_key = <pub_key>
            }
}
```

Any help!

Comment: Just want to run bash commands in the nodes? Any way is OK?

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes, I would be open to try out suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no straightforward solution for this one. Static IP was not the right way to do it and hence, I ended up writing a wrapper around terraform. I did not want to run my init scripts on every node that comes up but only one of the nodes. So essentially, now that wrapper communicates with terraform to first deploy only one node which executes cloud-init. After this, it recalls the function to scale terraform and brings up rest of the desired number of instances. In the cloud-init script, I have a check of `kubectl get no` where if I receive the size as more than one node, I simply skip the cloud-init commands.

Answer (score 0):

AKS does not expose the nodes of it to the Internet. And you just can connect the nodes through the master of the cluster. If you want to run a few bash commands in the nodes, you can use the SSH connection that makes a pod as a helper to connect to the nodes, see the steps about [SSH node access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh).

Also, you can add the NAT rules for the nodes in the Load Balancer, then you can also SSH to the nodes through the Load Balancer public IP. But it's not a secure way. So I do not suggest this way.

Comment: But terraform does not spit out the public IP of the loadbalancer. I am trying to solve that issue out

Comment: @AnshulVerma You can create the public IP with static method when you create the AKs cluster. Then you can output the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend just running a daemonset that performs the bash commands on the nodes. As any scale or update operations are going to remove or not have the updated config you are performing on the nodes.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I do not need it to run on every node - just on one of the node for one time is fine